# What are the obstacle penalties for darkness?

Tags: vision-and-light, burning-wheel

In Burning Wheel, darkness causes obstacle penalties; I think they range from +1 to +4 Ob. The Elven common trait Keen Sight supports this.

I can't, however, find the actual penalties in the Gold edition of the core book. What are the obstacle penalties for darkness and where are they located in the core book, if anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the Mage Light spell description:

> There are four types of darkness: dim light, lantern, torch, twilight
>   (+1 Ob); candlelight, moonlight (+2 Ob); gloom or near dark, starlight
>   (+3 Ob); and complete darkness or darkness indoors or underground (+4
>   Ob)

There's also a paragraph on Light in Range and Cover -> Weather, Terrain and Light